# How to Prevent Users from knowing when I edited my pages?

Tags: google-classic-sites, access-control

In Google Sites, I have Access settings set up such that even though my website is publicly viewable, only I can see it's "Revisition History" and "Site Activity".

[image]

However, when users (a user that isn't logon to my Google Account) search my website using the search box in the top right hand corner of my webpage, this is what they see:

[image]

How do I stop the edit-history information from getting displayed?

Comment: Do the results show *all* revisions? Or do they show just the time of the last one?

Comment: Yes just the time of the last. But I would not like the users to see any dates at all..

Comment: Unless you're trying to hoax something, there's no reason to hide revision dates. That piece of data serves 2 important functions: 1) allows search engines to rank and filter your page properly and 2) shows to your visitors that the data is recent or old. The only privacy concern here is that it shows the name of the person who did the last change.

Answer (score 1):

Dnbrv is correct that the data needs to be indexed for search engines
I'd look through your analytics and if other users are actually seeing these timestamps, and it really bothers you, you could always take the search box off under 'Site Layout'
The analytics won't lie, just because someone could potentially see this info doesnt mean anyone actually is
Jon